# Run-Time Errors Over Multiple Layers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, runtime-error

I notice that when Flash warns me of run-time errors over multiple layers of script the line of error doesn't seem accurate (I'm pretty sure it just tells me what line of all the code the error is on, not the specific line of the layer I'm working with). The warning doesn't even tell me what layer the problem is on. For example:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   _example_fla::MainTimeline/my_function()[_example_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:523]

Is there anyway I can get Flash to tell me what layer, frame and line (on that layer) the issue occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, Flash doesn't give this information about layers. You have to do a little math.

The error is occurring on Frame 1 (you can see that after the :: on the message.)

To find the layer, you have to count the lines of code on each layer, from the top down. Flash sees it all as one long block of code. Thus, FOR EXAMPLE, if layer 1 has 452 lines, layer 2 has 12, and layer 3 has 59, you can do the math and find your error on line 57 of that third layer.

523-452=71

71-12=59

Thus, line 57, layer 3

This can get annoying. It is for this reason that the standard practice at my company for code on the timeline is to put all code (except, usually, event listeners)on a layer by itself, at the top of the stack, called SCRIPTS. Nothing else lives in that layer - it is just empty with code. It makes life so much easier.

Comment: Thank you Jason for your excellent answer. It's good to see someone with experience helping others in the coding community. By the way, I also used to write all my code on a single frame, but unfortunately my code got too long for me to easily navigate.

Comment: Mm, yeah, that can be an issue. It is good to divide up your code. Our standard is this:

1) All code NOT directly relating to the timeline and visual objects on the stage should go into the Document Class and, if desired, additional AS3 classes.

2) All code directly relating to the timeline and visual objects in general should go on the SCRIPTS layer.

3) Event listeners and their functions should go on the layer containing the target object in question. (Keep response functions small, having them call other functions on the SCRIPTS layer when possible.)